# Don't automatically post a "$year Community Moderator Election" meta post

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, election

Every election, the Community user posts an announcement post.  [Here they are on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=questions&sort=newest), for instance.  In 2020, they appear to have started becoming [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) as well (which a Stack Overflow moderator [quickly rectified](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/399104/timeline) that year with the edit summary "no").

No one [knows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352385/2017-community-moderator-election#comment493705_352385) [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337570/2016-community-moderator-election#comment410960_337570) they exist.  There's [often a fight over closing them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380884/march-2019-community-moderator-election#comment674969_380884).  They contain [confusing advice on how to ask candidates questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412361/208273).  There's only one non-deleted answer to any of them on Stack Overflow (plus two more deleted answers).

In addition, the election is already featured prominently in the sidebar once it's underway, and before that, the question collection post is [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), and contains a link to the election itself.

This post seems entirely redundant.  Can we remove it from the process?

Comment: Plus, they get [triple posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399112/why-was-the-latest-election-mistakenly-started-three-times) if a dev makes a mistake.