# Why is an election mentioned twice in the sidebar?

Tags: support, election, sidebar, featured-tag

*[Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange is currently having an election, and the site sidebar currently looks like this:

[image: Politics Stack Exchange Sidebar]

As you can see, the election is mentioned under the section with heading **Upcoming Events**, and also under the section labeled **Featured on Meta** (note: the question was automatically posted and featured).

Is there a reason for mentioning the election twice in the sidebar?

Comment: Related: [Don't automatically post a "$year Community Moderator Election" meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371023)

Answer (score 14):

The first link points to [the election event itself](https://politics.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).

The second link, which is located in the section labeled *Featured on Meta*, is [a meta post about the election](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6379/2022-community-moderator-election) with a description of the election phases and a link to the election event.

The third link points to the [meta post where candidates answer questions posed by the community](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6354). It happens to [have become a Hot Network Question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/6354/timeline) (based on [the HNQ formula with tweaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/341145)) and thus is displayed in the *Hot Meta Posts* section.

While the pages all concern the election, they are distinct and not technically connected.

Comment: I should have made this more clear, but I was referring to the featured meta post, not the hot meta post.

Comment: Ah - so many links! I have updated this answer to address the link under the _Featured on Meta_ section