# Could election announcement posts be formatted better?

Tags: feature-request, election, information-display

The moderation election post posted by the community bot looks something like this, in this case for [Codegolf.SE](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/25150/revisions):

> The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!
>
> Community moderator elections have three phases:
>
> 1. Nomination phase
> 2. Primary phase
> 3. Election phase
>
> Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.
>
> Please visit the official election page at
>
> https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election
>
> for more detail, and to participate!
>
> If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

However I think the format is not really appealing, maybe we can change it to something like this?

> ### The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!
>
> Community moderator elections have three phases:
>
> 1. Nomination phase [In progress/Complete]
> 2. Primary phase [Skipped/In progress/Complete]
> 3. Election phase [In progress/Complete]
>
> Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.
>
> Please visit the [official election page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election) for more detail, and to participate!
>
> If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta - just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

I welcome any other suggestions up for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) too!

[@Ryan_M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165261/ryan-m):

> Or better yet, [don't post them at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371023/165261)

Comment: Any feature request also includes discussion, in a way, as answer can discuss the request, suggest other ways to do it, etc.

Comment: relevant since we are talking about updating election stuff - the help center could probably have a bit of info about elections too

Comment: Or better yet, [don't post them at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371023/165261).

Comment: Good point @RyanM since the election is already on the sites featured, I'll add your link into the question as well :3 *thanks*